# Most efficient way to insert a changed column's difference value into a table with matching columns?

Tags: mysql, insert, unique

It's difficult to word this into a single sentence question.  Here's the premise:

I have two tables structured like this:

```
create table TableA(
id int, <-- this is a unique ID in TableA but not in TableB
value1 int,
value2 int,
value3 int,
value4 int,
value5 int,
value6 int,
update_time DATETIME
)
```

and

```
create table TableB(
id int,
value1 int,
value2 int,
value3 int,
value4 int,
value5 int,
value6 int,
update_time DATETIME
)
```

`TableA` has 100,000 rows of data (The latest copy of an API response). Every hour the API returns new data for each ID in `TableA` and the API response updates `TableA` with the latest data for each unique ID.  ALL of the responses are saved into `TableB` for data analysis over time (So every hour 100,000 rows are added to `TableB`.).  However, not all of the data changes every hour.  In fact, the majority of data does not change at all.

Here is how I would like to structure it:
Let's say the API returns data for `id = 432` and all of the values are the same except for `value4`, `value4` contains 505043 (instead of 505000 which is the value currently stored in `TableA` for `id=432`).  I want to take 505043 - 505000 = 43 and store this into `TableB`:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (id, value6) VALUES (432, 43)
```

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?  My initial thought is to retrieve the data from `TableA` into the PHP `cron` script, compute the data difference (if any) and then construct the insert statement accordingly.  But since this process is going to happen so many times per second, I want to be sure I'm using the most efficient method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is update_time the same for all of the rows in TableA that are updated due to a certain API return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) which inserts a row into TableB whenever a row is inserted or updated in TableA.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4753878/190597) of how to use a trigger to insert a row into a table whenever a row is inserted in another table.