# MySQL, Synchronise two tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two data base A & B, in each one I have a table called answer, I want to use the 2nd one as an archive table, I want to create a trigger that copies the last inserted row in A.answer to B.answer.

Here what I did

```
  CREATE TRIGGER `a` AFTER INSERT ON `A`.`answer` 
     FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `B`.`answer`  SELECT * FROM `answer`
```

This trigger works, but copy all the answers inserted in A.answer to B.answer.
The problem is : I dont want to copy all answers, but only the last one.
(remark : I dont know the id of the inserted answer, so dont tell me to add a ' WHERE answer.id = xx ').
Thanks for your help

Comment: Add `SELECT * FROM answer ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` and that gives you the last answer. And try to be polite.

Comment: Possible (near) duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753878/how-to-program-a-mysql-trigger-to-insert-row-into-another-table

Comment: Nice solution N.B ... I have a 3go table, and need to order it every time I insert a new row (5000 rows inserted by minute).

Thx ethrbunny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your trigger this way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `a` AFTER INSERT ON `A`.`answer` 
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO `B`.`answer` VALUES (NEW.col1, NEW.col2, ..., NEW.colN)
```

where you have to specify all column names.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15d39/1).