# How to INSERT in one table and UPDATE in another in single QUERY?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently creating some sort of inventory system.

I have `master_tbl` where in I save the items. In `master_tbl`, I have column `qty_left` or the available stock left.

I also have the table `issuance_tbl` where in I save all the transaction in issuing items. 
In this table there is `issued_qty`.

My problem is how can I INSERT a row into `issuance_tbl` at the same time UPDATE the `master_tbl.qty_left`. (master_tbl.qty_left - issuance_tbl.issued_qty).

Is it possible?

Comment: Create a stored procedure.

Comment: Use triggers on insert

Comment: Why not using 2 queries?

Comment: coz, I have a single form, that accept record for issuance_tbl. also includen in that form is the 'issued_qty' that i needed to update the master_tbl.qty_left.

Comment: look this answer, maybe it help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/4754333/2550094

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using Stored Procedure. You can have bunch of SQL statements with error handling and ACID transactions in one place. This is because if your first query executes and the second fails, you may need to rollback transactions. Stored procedures allow all this fancy but reliable stuff.

You can start here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569

Comment: I'm newbie programmer and i have no idea about Stored Procedure. :(

Comment: @ChocoMartin: there are millions of tutorials regarding stored procedures on the internet  (the MySQL has one as well - and you did read the manual, did you?). You should really read them.

Comment: Then I would suggest to invest sometime in it. It will really help you write enterprise level applications in the future. You will find thousands of examples and tutorials on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

here is the example:

```
    <form method="post">
    QTY:<input type="text" name="qty_left"></input>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update"></form>

   <?php
         ////////your config db
     $qty = $_POST['qty_left'];
     if(isset($_POST['submit']);
     $sql = mysql_query("insert into issuance_tbl (issued_qty) values (".$qty.") ");
     $sql1 = mysql_query("update master_table set qty_left= ".$qty."");
     ?>
```

Comment: `UPDATE FROM` is deprecated.

Comment: i forgot to remove the from

Comment: anyway, all mysql_* are deprecated. and your update query will be based on what `where` condition ?

Comment: it depends on the database that you need to update from where condition if its a primary key or foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely confident that 'If there's any way to do such thing':
You need to do it in steps, LIKE THIS:

```
$result = $this->db->insert($table);//Example function to insert inventory item
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();//Example function to get the id of inserted item
if($result)
$res = $this->db->update($id,$data,$table);//Example function to update data of quantity table

if(!$res)
{
$this->db->delete($insert_id,$table);s
$result = '-1';
}
return $result;
```

Hope this might help

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
...
$issued_qty = '10'; //some value

$insert_query = "insert into issuance_table (issued_qty, ...) values ('$issued_qty', ... ) ;";    
$update_query = "update master_tbl set qty_left = (qty_left - ".$issued_qty.")  where ....";    
mysqli_multi_query($con, $insert_query.$update_query);
```