# SQL Populating key/value table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a few SQL tables, one for users, one for configurations, one for a key/value for users' configurations.

What I want to do is, when adding a new entry to the users table, I want to populate the key/value table with one row for all the available configurations rows in the configuration table.

So if the config table has these rows:

```
Setting1
Setting2
Setting3
```

I would want to end up with something like this for the key/value table:

```
NewUser | Seeting1 | OFF
NewUser | Seeting2 | OFF
NewUser | Seeting3 | OFF
```

Not sure how to actually add that to the key/value table (what the syntax is).
I suppose it can be done as a trigger based on additions to the users table also.

Comment: So are you wanting to just get a Select which will give you your design or...?

Comment: no schema...no queries....no efforts shown......you expect an answer...seriously????

Comment: Are you looking for a trigger?  See if [the following post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753878/how-to-program-a-mysql-trigger-to-insert-row-into-another-table) gives you a hint.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to accomplish this in a single SQL by using an INSERT/SELECT statement. The one caveat is that you should store a column in the `settings` table called `default_value` that stores the initial setting value when a user is created. If you have that column you could create the default values like so:

```
INSERT INTO user_settings (user_id, setting_id, value)
SELECT
  <user_id>,
  id,
  default_value
FROM
  settings
```

You could definitely trigger this statement on `INSERT` into the `users` table.