# TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE - copy to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE which copy the row that has just been updated in TABLE_1 to the TABLE_2.

This code raise an error after updated more than one row : SQL Error (1062): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

I know this code is not right but I just don't know how to manipulate the row that has been updated.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`companyERP`@`%` TRIGGER `trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `Table_1`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO Table_2 SELECT *
FROM Table_1;
END
```

Comment: The problem here is that you have copied the same structure for table_1 to table_2 including the primary key. Table_2's primary key needs to be a separate column not available in table_1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753878/how-to-program-a-mysql-trigger-to-insert-row-into-another-table

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`companyERP`@`%` TRIGGER `trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `Table_1`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO Table_2 SELECT new.Field1, newField2 ...
FROM Table_1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
/*
CREATE DEFINER=`companyERP`@`%` TRIGGER `trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `Table_1`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO Table_2 SELECT *
FROM Table_1;
END
*/

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `trigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `Table_1`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `Table_2`
    (`id_table_1`, `old_value`, `created_at`)
  VALUES
    (OLD.`id`, OLD.`value`, NOW());
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46272/1)</kbd>