# How can I write a trigger that can copy new row from a table on insertion to another table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables, creds and users.

**users**

`email  password  fullName  contact  city`

**creds**

`email  password`

I need a trigger which can copy `email` and `password` from `users` into `creds` upon insertion of new rows.

Comment: Please look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753878/how-to-program-a-mysql-trigger-to-insert-row-into-another-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this following trigger works for you.
More or less it will be like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_trigger
ON creds 
FOR INSERT
AS  
BEGIN 
    Insert into users(email, password, fullname, contact, city) 
    select distinct u.email, u.password
    from inserteduser u
    left join creds c
    on u.email = c.email and u.password = c.password
END;
```