# SQL Trigger - Update table A with sum(tableB.col) WHERE tableA.userID = tableB.userID

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I'm a pretty new database student...

I have two tables. User, and Trip.

Whenever a new Trip is added to the database, I want it to trigger an update on the User table in the "totalMiles" column. I want it to take the Trip.userID and change the value in the "totalMiles" column of only the user with the same User.userID as the Trip.userID entry.

I want it to take the sum from "tripMiles" where the Trip.userID = User.userID. userID is a foreign key in the Trip table from the User table.

right now I just have:

```
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost'TRIGGER 'DATABASE'.'Trip_AFTER_INSERT' 
AFTER INSERT ON 'Trip' FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE User
SET totalMiles=sum(tripMiles)
WHERE Trip.userID = User.userID;
END
```

The error I get is "unknown column 'Trip.userID' in 'where clause'.

I googled and searched through a couple of posts here but I didn't really find anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to program a MySQL trigger to insert row into another table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753878/how-to-program-a-mysql-trigger-to-insert-row-into-another-table)

Answer (score 0):

Just change de "User.userID" on where clausule to "NEW.userID"

The "New" object means your new TRIP added...

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'Trip_AFTER_INSERT'
AFTER INSERT ON 'Trip' FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE User
SET totalMiles=sum(tripMiles)
WHERE User.userID = NEW.userID;
END
```

If you want more, see documentation here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

and here

[How to program a MySQL trigger to insert row into another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753878/how-to-program-a-mysql-trigger-to-insert-row-into-another-table)

Comment: This changed it to a different error. Now it's #1111 - Invalid use of group function. I'll read the documentation as well though. I don't really want it to insert into a new row in the user table, I want it to update a column in the user table where the new trip.userID = user.userID.

Comment: is i understand that... but see the difference... the NEW object is the NEW TRIP added... so if u have the trip name, to access just write: New.tripName.

edited: Try this:

    CREATE TRIGGER 'Trip_AFTER_INSERT'
    AFTER INSERT ON 'Trip' FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    UPDATE User
    SET totalMiles=sum(tripMiles)
    WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
    END

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems with your statement, starting with the single quotes.  One method is to recalculate the sum:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DATABASE.Trip_AFTER_INSERT 
AFTER INSERT ON Trip FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE User u 
        SET totalMiles = (SELECT sum(t.tripMiles) FROM Trip t WHERE t.userId = u.userId)
        WHERE u.userID = new.userID;
END;
```

The is overkill, though.  If `totalMiles` is previously correct, then just adjust the value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DATABASE.Trip_AFTER_INSERT 
AFTER INSERT ON Trip FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE User u 
        SET totalMiles = u.totalMile + new.tripMiles - old.tripMailes; 
        WHERE u.userID = new.userID;
END;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. After looking through your code it seems pretty obvious. I was kind of thrown into a project after having only a basic database class so far so I'm very appreciative for the help!